# RUBY- one line statement mistake

Tags: ruby

when I try to write this one line if else, an error comes up. How should I fix it?

```rb
def odd_or_even(number)
  number % 2 == 0 ? return "even" : return "odd"
end

odd_or_even(3)
```

Comment: remove both `return`s

Comment: Also cosmetic thing, but consider `number.even? ? "even" : "odd"`

Comment: `number.even? and "even" or "odd"` probably also works, matter of opinion whether the `?:` or `and/or` is more readable

Comment: @Arkku - As long as I code I have never met `condition and sth or sth` as an alternative to ternary operator. I guess it works the same, but it looks at least weird (to me, naturally, which is not really a good argument)

Comment: @BroiSatse Yeah, it's not very idiomatic Ruby, so I would also go with the ternary operator here. A similar construct is quite common in shell script as `command && foo || bar`. In Ruby I've seen `foo or bar` and `foo and bar` with some frequency, but admittedly can't immediately think of a real-world example with both `and` and `or`.

Comment: "when I try to write this one line if else, an error comes up. How should I fix it?" – Reading the error message would be a good start. If you don't understand what it says, you can try googling, or asking a question about it on [so].

Answer (score 1):

The return is in the wrong place. You cant have spaces in the 2 outcomes from the ternary operator.
Either you remove the return or put parenthesis around them.

```rb
# cleanest way
number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"

# if it has to include the return in the outcomes 
number % 2 == 0 ? (return "even") : (return "odd")

# if it needs a return
return number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"
```